# Update objects inside the JSON based on condition in arrays with PostgreSQL

Tags: json, postgresql

I need to update a record where condition matched. Consider there is table with column name myjson

**table name:** mytable
**column name:** myjson
**type:** jsonb

Sample JSON

```
{
   "id":"1",
   "activity":[
      {
         "message":"This is test",
         "user":{
         "uid":"101",
         "name":"xyz"
         }
      },
      {
         "message":"this is sample",
         "user":{
         "uid":"102",
         "name":"abc"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I would like to update the message based on uid, The sample code look like below

```
UPDATE mytable
SET myjson = myjson->'activity'
FROM (
    SELECT 
         jsonb_agg(
             CASE WHEN myjson->'activity'->'user'->> 'uid' = '101' THEN
                 jsonb_set(myjson->'activity', '{message}', '"xxx"')
             ELSE myjson->'activity'  END
       ) as json_array
    FROM
       mytable
) s;

SELECT 
    jsonb_pretty(myjson) 
FROM mytable
```

Expected result is

```
{
   "id":"1",
   "activity":[
      {
         "message":"This is test",
         "user":{
         "id":"101",
         "name":"xxx"
         }
      },
      {
         "message":"this is sample",
         "user":{
         "id":"102",
         "name":"abc"
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Does your table have only a single row?

Comment: @Bergi have two rows one is id  another one is myjson

Comment: You mean two columns. But how many *rows* does your table have?

Comment: @Bergi Only two columns, around 300 rows